# Implementing a MPC for regulation of ventilation system based on energy costs

Tags: python, gekko

We are a group of three members who are writing a bachelor thesis together about implementing MPC in a shopping mall here in Tromsø. Our main goal is to optimize the indoor temperature in based on power consumption. The issue is declaring all of our input variables and declaring the object function correctly.

All the input variables and are pulled from a pyads server from our Bechoff IPC where we get our real-time sensor data. We are also pulling weather data where we get the outdoor temperature for the next 12 hours in an array.

Our equations for the temperatures in the ventilation system:

```py
T5_max = T1 + n1*(T3-T1)
T6_max = T5_max + n2*((V*rho*C_water)*n2*(T8-T7))/V_flow
T2_max = T5_max + T6_max + (n3 * V*rho*C_air*(T5-T1))/(V_flow * rho * C)
T5_min = T6_min = T2_min = T1
```

`n1`, `n2`, and `n3` are all constants. (efficiency rates). All the `T` values are real-time sensor data. `V_flow` is constant. Our equations for the temperature in the mall.

```
sum(T3)dT/dt = (T3 - (UA*(T3-T1))/V*rho*C_air + ((T2-T3) * V_flow/Volume) dt
T_room = T3 + (sum(T3)dT/dt)
```

`UA` and `Volume` are known constants. We are also getting the power prices for a 24-hour period and the amount of people in the building. These are not implemented in the equations yet since we just want to get a basic model running first.

So, based on these equations we want to set the optimal temperature for `t5`, `t6`, and `t2` to get the `T_room` in a range of 18-24 degrees. In the most cost-efficient way.

Hope someone can help us with implementing this in an easy way.

```py
#Væskebatteri
NomEff_E2 = m.Param(value=50)   

#Gjenvinner 
n1 = 0.8
#E1 = VolumFlow*rho_luft*Cv_luft*(T5-uteTemp)

# Parameters
Volum = m.Const(value=39000) #m^3
VolumFlow = m.Const(value=5) #m^3/s
rho_luft = m.Const(value=1.2) #kg/m^3
rho_vann = m.Const(value=1000) #kg/m^3
Cv_vann = m.Const(value=4.18) #kJ/kgK
Cv_luft = m.Const(value=1.006) #kJ/kgK
NomEff_El = m.Const(value=100) #KW
T1 = m.Const(value=-10)#C
UA_verdi = m.Const(value=100) #W/C

t5 = m.Var() 
t6 = m.Var() 
t3 = m.Var() 
t2 = m.Var()


t5.value = T1
t6.value = T1
t2.value = T1
t3.VALUE = 18

#lower 
t3.lb = 18
t5.lb = T1
t6.lb = T1
t2.lb = T1

#upper
t5.ub = T1 + n1*(t3-T1)
t6.ub = T1 + n1*(t3-T1) + NomEff_E2/(VolumFlow*rho_luft*Cv_luft)
t2.ub = T1 + n1*(t3-T1) + NomEff_E2/(VolumFlow*rho_luft*Cv_luft)
                        + NomEff_El/(VolumFlow*rho_luft*Cv_luft)
t3.ub = 25

m.Equation(t3.dt == (t3-(UA_verdi*(t3-T1)))/
    (Volum*rho_luft*Cv_luft)+((t2-t3)*(VolumFlow/Volum)))

E1 = m.Param(VolumFlow*rho_luft*Cv_luft*(t5-T1))
E2 = m.Param(VolumFlow*rho_luft*Cv_luft*(t6-t5))
E3 = m.Param(VolumFlow*rho_luft*Cv_luft*(t2-t6))

n2 = m.Const(value = 0.2)
n3 = m.Const(value = 1)
spottpris = m.Const(value = 0.7)
effektledd = m.Const(value=15)

m.Obj((-E1 + E2*n2 + E3*n3)*(spottpris+effektledd))

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.solve(disp=False)
print(t3.VALUE, t5.VALUE, t6.VALUE, t2.VALUE)
```

This is what we were working on yesterday, but we can clearly tell that this isn't the way. Here we tried to only simulate with constant values and the variable declaration may not be the same as the equations above. We tried to follow the [APMonitor example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH753YX2K1A&t=422s).

Consider us stupid.

Edit: Added a figure for a better explanation of our problem

[image: Figure for ventilation system.]

Edit 2: Updated equations and hopefully more describing.

[image]
[image]

The system operates sequentially using up available energy at each point before tapping of the next. (E1 -> E2 -> E3)
The objective is to find the optimal T2 temperature set point for the air handling unit that minimizes costs. The spotprice array will be an array with twelve constants.

Comment: Glad to see you are trying out GEKKO. GEKKO doesn't support dynamic (defined by equations) bounds on variables. Do the upper bounds for t5, t6 and t2 really need to be in terms of t3? The bounds can often either be broadened to handle this or dynamic bounds can be accommodated in the objective.

Comment: When you finish your project, please consider posting the files, data, and report so that others can also benefit from your work. Here is a list of other projects that may also be inspiration for yours: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ProjectLab

Comment: If you see the last edit, I added a picture of the whole system. We think the equations should be in term of t3 since that's our feedback from the system. @DanielHill

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The update definitely helps, but is still a little unclear. In your formulation above which variables are the degrees of freedom that can be manipulated by the optimizer? Are E1, E2 and E3 what you are expecting the controller to manipulate directly? If you can formulate ALL the details in the problem including constants in standard form it helps clarify the mathematical problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time in Tromsø, so this is cool work to see. Here are a few general guidelines that should help.

1. Bounds for GEKKO variables cannot include GEKKO equations. They must evaluate to specific values that don't change during the optimization.
2. If variable bounds must be dynamic or vary depending on other variables in the problem they must be formulated as equations rather than as bounds in the variable declarations. See reworked code example below.
3. You can use normal Python values for constants that are not time-dependent and are not being optimized. This often keeps the code a little cleaner and easier to work with.
4. Try and define variable upper and lower bounds when you declare the GEKKO varible. If they must be defined later use the `UPPER` and `LOWER` properties  rather than `ub` and `lb`, which are not defined.
5. If the program hangs with no visible progress(what happened when I first ran your code), you may have an unreported error on the remote server (default solution method). Solving the problem locally (`m = GEKKO(remote=False)`) can help get around this. [Docs](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=remote#remote)
6. The correct syntax for time-derivatives is `t3.dt()` not `t3.dt`. This one trips up a lot of people and was a problem in your code. If you ever get a "Model Expression" error it's worth checking to make sure you get this correct.
7. If you run into "Solution Not Found", your problem is likely mathmatically infeasible. You can open the solution directory (`m.open_folder()`) if you are running with `remote=False` and look at the `infeasibilities.txt` to see which equations are infeasible. If you add "names" to your variables like I did in the code example below it can help with reading the infeasibilities file.

Below is a working example of the code you posted. I have changed some variables names to help those that may not be familiar with Norwegian as well as simplified some things. I also added a slack variable to your first equation and the objective function to make the problem feasible.

There's a lot to take in there, so certainly let me know in the comments if any of this does not make sense.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Normal Python values can be used if the value is not 
# being optimized and is not time-dependent
NomEff_E2 = 50
n1 = 0.8            # recycle fraction
n2 = 0.2
n3 = 1
V = 39000           # m^3
AirFlow = 5         # m^3/s
rho_air = 1.2       # kg/m^3
rho_water = 1000    # kg/m^3
Cv_water = 4.18     # kJ/kgK
Cv_air = 1.006      # kJ/kgK
NomEff_El = 100     # KW
T1 = -10            # C, UteTemp
UA = 100            # W/C

# These will probably become m.parameters when you use real data
spotPrice = m.Const(value = 0.7)
effektledd = m.Const(value=15)

# The bounds on variables must be fixed values (not equations)
t5 = m.Var(T1, lb=T1, name='t5') 
t6 = m.Var(T1, lb=T1, name='t6') 
t3 = m.Var(18, lb=18, ub=25, name='t3') 
t2 = m.Var(T1, lb=T1, name='t2')

slack = m.Var(fixed_initial=False)

m.Equation(t3.dt() == (t3-(UA*(t3-T1)))/(V*rho_air*Cv_air)+(t2-t3)*(AirFlow/V) + slack) 

# The upper bounds expressed as equations
m.Equation(t5 <= T1 + n1*(t3-T1))
m.Equation(t6 <= T1 + n1*(t3-T1) + NomEff_E2/(AirFlow*rho_air*Cv_air))
m.Equation(t2 <= T1 + n1*(t3-T1) + NomEff_E2/(AirFlow*rho_air*Cv_air)
                        + NomEff_El/(AirFlow*rho_air*Cv_air))

E1 = m.Param(AirFlow*rho_air*Cv_air*(t5-T1))
E2 = m.Param(AirFlow*rho_air*Cv_air*(t6-t5))
E3 = m.Param(AirFlow*rho_air*Cv_air*(t2-t6))

m.Obj((-E1 + E2*n2 + E3*n3)*(spotPrice+effektledd)) + slack**2

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.solve(disp=False)
print(t3.VALUE, t5.VALUE, t6.VALUE, t2.VALUE)
```

Comment: One other thought. You are currently using IMODE 3, which is not for dynamic systems, so time is not accounted for. For MPC you will probably want to change your IMODE to a dynamic one ([Docs](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imode.html#imode-1)) and add a  time array (m.time). Here is a [full MPC example](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#model-predictive-control)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers you provided, it really helped us out. 
Is there any way to set up some parameters besides the upper boundaries for t3,t5,t6. In our system these values are different temperatures inside the ventilation system, which represent the temperature between the different control elements. Take T2 for an example, we want that to be used to the minimum unless it's needed, since that's the control element that uses the most energy.

Comment: @Kneven You can use as many `m.Equation` and m.Param` statements as you want and they can be functions of other parameters or variables. You can also add/manipulate any terms you would like to `m.Obj` to drive the optimization in the right direction. The art of this work is to properly efficiently formulate and balance the right terms/eqns, which I can't really do without a clear full mathematical description of the problem and objective. If you add those to your question, I can see if I can help you out more.

Comment: Sorry for a late response. We have been trying and failing for a couple of days, and went over our equations with our mentor. 
We think our equations make sense but the temperature and the energy from your example need be dependent on each other. So the more energy we use, the higher T2 would rise.  Is there any good solutions for that? 

We are having a struggle with understanding the different puzzle pieces Param, Var, MV, FV and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure if you get updates when I comment on the thread so I just tag you in case.